# opencv 3.0.0-dev python bindings not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, binding

I am on ubuntu 14.04.02, i have python, cython and numpy installed and updated.
i pulled the latest sources of open cv from http://github.com/itseez/opencv, compiled according to the documentation...
when trying to run the python source i pulled from https://github.com/shantnu/FaceDetect/
it's giving me the following error :

> modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "face_detect.py", line 21, in 
>      flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

to make sure i have the python bindings i typed the following in the terminal:
python

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

it returned the following
'3.0.0-dev'

what could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

the cv2.cv submodule got removed in opencv3.0, also some constants were changed.

please use cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE instead

(do a `help(cv2)` to see the updated constants)

Comment: That worked, Thank You. and after typing help(cv2) in, under DATA i found  CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE = 2
but I'm unsure what to make of this constant (how it's relative to the implementation)

Answer (score 6):

Apologies for the bump, but the above did not work for me, and I found an alternate "solution", but it may have unwanted side effects, given I know SFA about openCV.

The simple solution is just set it to 0.

```
  # Detect faces in the image
```

> ```
> faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
>     gray,
>     scaleFactor=1.1,
>     minNeighbors=5,
>     minSize=(30, 30),
> #    flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
>     flags = 0
> )
> ```

As you can see... i just set it to 0 and could move on with my life.

I tried all number of combinations, and I couldn't get the CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE working.

[This openCV doco explaination](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) gives me nadda, zip, nothing but confusion.

> flags – Parameter with the same meaning for an old cascade as in the function cvHaarDetectObjects. It is not used for a new cascade.

That cleared it up...

Anyway, the example on openCV hard codes it to 0.

Comment: That seems like a simple way to do it. man from problems between versions to lack of proper documentation, OpenCV sure is a pain.