# OpenCV-Python cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, constants, video-capture

Currently, I am using opencv 3.1.0, and I encountered the following error when executing the following code:

```
post_frame = cap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
```

I got the following error Message:

File "videoOperation.py", line 37, in 
    pos_frame = cap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES'

The code should be written in the following format when using OpenCV 2.x:

```
post_frame = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
```

From [opencv 3.0.0-dev python bindings not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013009/opencv-3-0-0-dev-python-bindings-not-working-properly), I know that

> the cv2.cv submodule got removed in opencv3.0, also some constants were changed

But the cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES didn't work for me, So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try typing this instead:

```
post_frame = cap.get(1) #CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES = 1
```

If you type `help('cv2')` in the Python shell, you will find some modifications to the syntax.

```
output truncated

...
CAP_PROP_PAN = 33
CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO = 2
CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES = 1
CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC = 0
CAP_PROP_PVAPI_BINNINGX = 304
CAP_PROP_PVAPI_BINNINGY = 305
CAP_PROP_PVAPI_DECIMATIONHORIZONTAL = 302
...
```

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for this:

```
post_frame = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should search for CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES in /usr/include/opencv2 or /usr/local/include etc. ,whichever is in your makefile include path . It would be in videoio/videoio_c.h or /videoio/legacy/constants_c.h . Use this in your include path #include  . This is the right way .