# how to use compareHist function opencv

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

```
img = cv2.imread('mandrill.png')
histg = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

if len (sys.argv) < 2:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "<image>..."
    sys.exit (1)

for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    im = cv2.imread (fn)

histr = cv2.calcHist([im],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
a = cv2.compareHist(histr,histg,cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL)
print a
```

I am trying to use the code above to compare the correlation between histograms `histr` and `histg` when I run the code the I get the error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
```

It seems that CV3 the names of the various correlation functions have changed. What are the names of the various correlation functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013009/opencv-3-0-0-dev-python-bindings-not-working-properly

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The opencv version you are using has `cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL` renamed to `cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL`

The function name changes are as follows (left hand side shows the names for `opencv2`, right hand side shows the name for the latest version of opencv(`opencv3`)):

```
cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL:: cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL
cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CHISQR :: cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR/ cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR_ALT
cv2.cv.CV_COMP_INTERSECT :: cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT
cv2.cv.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA :: cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA
```

Comment: It worked. Please do you know the methods for Bhattacharyya, chi square and intersection

Comment: Please add the required deprecated APIs' in the question by editing.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that not all metrics behave the same. For Correlation and Intersection, a bigger value means more similarity. It's the contrary for the others.

Answer (score 12):

As Zdar mentioned it looks like the constants have been renamed in opencv3.0 to:

```
cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL
cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR
cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT 
cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA
a = cv2.compareHist(histr,histg,cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL) should work
```

Answer (score 6):

sample code for compare histogram in OpenCV 3.2

```
import cv2

path='location_of_images'
im1 = cv2.imread(path+'/'+'first.jpg',0)
hist1 = cv2.calcHist([im1],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

im2 = cv2.imread(path+'/'+'second.jpg',0)
hist2 = cv2.calcHist([im2],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

a=cv2.compareHist(hist1,hist2,cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA)

print a
```

return value show how close to your test image with compared one.
example: `cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA` method gives zero(0.0) for the same image.
other methods are `cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR,cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR_ALT,cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL    cv2.HISTCMP_HELLINGER,cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT,cv2.HISTCMP_KL_DIV.`

Comment: Thanks for the simple yet very helpful code. I have seen a lot of codes here and elsewhere which tend to complicate things a lot. _Question_: I understand that we are supplying the `[im2]` to calcHist, but what does the rest of the function do: ([0], None,[256],[0,256])

Comment: cv2.calcHist(images, channels, mask, histSize, ranges[, hist[, accumulate]])

Comment: Can you describe the use cases for this method? I tried using it to compare images of the same things/areas but at different angles. But the results weren't really good. In what cases could using histograms work well?